# Adding a status bar, but it doesn't fit in with the rest of the controls

Tags: c#

I finished writing a set of controls, and suddenly thought "hey let's add a status bar".
So I went to add a status strip at the bottom of my main form, but it was blocking the bottom of any control.

It looks like it's just placing itself over any existing controls.

How can I add a status bar and have all of the other controls automatically adjust themselves to allow my status bar to appear at the bottom of the form without interfering with the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your other controls are docked, just send it to the back using the context menu and they'll adjust automatically. (Right-click > Send to Back)

Comment: ah, there we go. Now it looks better.